# Переделать SQL запрос для Yii2

Tags: sql, yii2, запрос

Есть старый сайт в котором есть таблица, выводящая некоторые данные.
Данные в таблице выводятся в зависимости от того, под каким логином был осуществлен вход.
Сначала происходит выбор параметра этим запросом:

```
$sql = "select ID_REC from S_USER where ID_PODR=$podr and NAME_USER='$login' and PASS_USER='$pass'";
```

После чего выполняется следующий запрос, выводящий нужные данные в таблицу:

```
select 
    MOVE.ID_REC, 
    S_IZDANIE.IND_IZD, 
    S_IZDANIE.NAME_IZD, 
    MOVE.NOM_IZD, 
    MOVE.DATE_IZD, 
    MOVE.CENA_REAL, 
    MOVE.COL_IZD, 
    NAKL.NUM_NAKL,
    (MOVE.COL_IZD - MOVE.COL_REAL) as COL_OST, 
    MOVE.COL_REAL, 
    MOVE.COL_SPIS,
    MOVE.PRIZN_SPIS
from MOVE 
    inner join NAKL on (MOVE.ID_NAKL = NAKL.ID_REC) and (NAKL.TYPE_NAKL in(2,3)) 
    inner join S_IZDANIE on (MOVE.ID_IZD = S_IZDANIE.ID_REC) 
where 
    ((NAKL.GOD = ".$this->year.") and 
     (NAKL.MES = ".$this->month.") and 
     (NAKL.ID_PODR_POL = ".$this->podrazd."))
order by S_IZDANIE.NAME_IZD, MOVE.DATE_IZD";
```

Каким образом переделать данные запросы, что бы они работали на Yii2 ? Я новичок и это мой первый фраемворк, который я изучаю, и попутно пишу в нем проект)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запросы в **Yii2** (ActiveQuery) осуществляются с помощью класса **ActiveRecord**.

1. "Выбор параметра" из таблицы **S_USER** (соответственно, у Вас должна быть модель, скажем, **User**)

   ```
   <?php 

   $user = User::find()
   ->select('ID_REC')
   ->where([
      'ID_PODR' => $podr,
      'NAME_USER' => $login,
      'PASS_USER' => $pass,])
   ->one(); ?>
   ```
2. "После чего выполняется следующий запрос" (соответственно, у Вас должна быть модель, скажем, **MOVE**) 
   Для удобства, занес выбираемые поля в отдельный массив.

```
$columns_array = [
      'MOVE.ID_REC',
      'S_IZDANIE.IND_IZD',
      'S_IZDANIE.NAME_IZD',
      'MOVE.NOM_IZD',
      'MOVE.DATE_IZD',
      'MOVE.CENA_REAL',
      'MOVE.COL_IZD',
      'NAKL.NUM_NAKL',
      '(MOVE.COL_IZD - MOVE.COL_REAL) as COL_OST',
      'MOVE.COL_REAL',
      'MOVE.COL_SPIS',
      'MOVE.PRIZN_SPIS'
    ];

$query = MOVE::find()->select($columns_array); 
$query->innerJoin('NAKL', 'MOVE.ID_NAKL = NAKL.ID_REC and NAKL.TYPE_NAKL in(2,3)); $query->innerJoin('S_IZDANIE', 'MOVE.ID_IZD = S_IZDANIE.ID_REC');$query->where([
'NAKL.GOD' = $this->year,
'NAKL.MES' = $this->month,
'NAKL.ID_PODR_POL' = $this->podrazd
])->orderBy('S_IZDANIE.NAME_IZD, MOVE.DATE_IZD')->all();
```

Это лишь пример конструктора запросов, подробнее можно почитать в доке http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html

Answer (score 1):

Все `SQL` запросы работают в `yii2` точно также как и везде. 
Смотрите в сторону :

- Query Builder
- Active Record

Приведу пример 2 запроса через конструктор запросов `queryBuilder`

```
$query = new yii\db\Query();
$query->select([
    'MOVE.ID_REC', 
    'S_IZDANIE.IND_IZD', 
    'S_IZDANIE.NAME_IZD', 
    'MOVE.NOM_IZD', 
    'MOVE.DATE_IZD', 
    'MOVE.CENA_REAL', 
    'MOVE.COL_IZD', 
    'NAKL.NUM_NAKL',
    '(MOVE.COL_IZD - MOVE.COL_REAL) as COL_OST', 
    'MOVE.COL_REAL', 
    'MOVE.COL_SPIS',
    'MOVE.PRIZN_SPIS'
])
->from(['MOVE'])
->innerJoin('NAKL', 'MOVE.ID_NAKL = NAKL.ID_REC and NAKL.TYPE_NAKL in(2,3)')
->innerJoin('S_IZDANIE', 'MOVE.ID_IZD = S_IZDANIE.ID_REC')
->where([
    'NAKL.GOD' => $this->year,
    'NAKL.MES' => $this->month,
    'NAKL.ID_PODR_POL' => $this->podrazd,
])
->orderBy([
    'S_IZDANIE.NAME_IZD' => SORT_DESC,
    'MOVE.DATE_IZD' => SORT_DESC,
]);

print_r($query->all());
```

Дока на оф сайте: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html